# Get id from page

Tags: apex, soql, community, salesforce-id

I am making a custom controller which is used to  create a user from the  account information but i am unable find id. How can i get account id to use in my controller. is there a method in salesforce which takes id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using custom controller, you can get it from page parameters. Try below code,

```
Id accId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
```